# How can I keep the color output of git status when piping it through grep?

Tags: grep, git, colors

I'm trying to compress the output of git status a bit, for a "system status" script that runs whenever I log in to an ssh session.  I'm hoping it'll nag at me and encourage me to commit more often!

```
git status | grep -v "git add\|git checkout\|no changes added"
```

Sadly it loses the coloring; any modified files are shown in the default font color, not red.

I've tried adding `--color=never` to the grep command, but that didn't make a difference, so I assume `git status` isn't adding color codes because of the pipe.  Since a few commands in linux have `--color=always` to get over this, I tried adding that to `git`, but it just complained about an unknown option.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I've discovered that you can add color options to the `.git/config` file in the project directory.  This did exactly what I wanted:

```
[color]
status = always
```

Comment: Instead of editing `.git/config` by hand, it's better to use `git config color.status always` to do it for you. You can also add `--global` or `--system` to set the preferences for all your repositories at once. See `man git-config` for details.

Comment: Or per command as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15884261/2099362): `git -c color.status=always status`

Comment: I came here not for status but for log, where `-c color.diff=always` solved it but took me a while to recognize that `status` in `color.status` stands for the status command, not for the color status.. so I hope this comment saves someone some time :-)